Test Room DAO implementation in kotlin multiplatform
I implemented a small app in kotlin multiplatform without any issues using Room.
But now I'm facing a challenge to create tests for the DAO because I need the Context to create a in memory database to run the tests in the common code.
The tests for iOS and android are 100% equal just the way I start the database is different because Android needs the Context.
I'm only interested in mobile deployment.
Do anyone knows how to solve this without copying the tests to the android and iOS tests folder (aka having tests duplicated)?
Edit 1:
I'm using the Expected and actual functions to create the room database for the android and iOS app, I'm having trouble creating the in memory database to use in the shared code tests because the in memory database for android needs the android Context.

Please have look here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-expect-actual.html#expected-and-actual-functions

I have that, but in the shared test, I don't have access to the android context to create the in memory room database to execute the tests.
The only thing that I found is to duplicate the tests in the android and iOS tests, and I don't want to do that because the tests are 100% equal the only thing that changes is the way to create the in memory database

I have a similar question here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/378189504

Thanks @BitwiseDEVS for the tip.
I tried that and it works, I also did the same with sqldelight.
But I want to run the tests in the android simulator because room is still alpha so it's kinda better to run the tests in the simulator also.

To solve this I made a gradle task that copy the tests from unit tests folder to instrumented tests and it works like a charm. The only downside of this is that every time I run the tests I have to run this task
